# DFT calculations

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-espresso, gromacs

What is the best way to learn DFT (Density Functional Theory) for beginners?
I want to learn DFT (both simulation and theory). I am a beginners in this field. What is the best way to learn it?

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10516/6055), [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/i-am-a-beginner-in-dft-what-are-some-resources-that-could-help-me-to-learn-the) and [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/123/are-there-any-online-course-video-lectures-available-on-density-functional-theor). On a personal note, I am also learning DFT. If you want to chat, you can hop over to [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117642) or [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107323) chatroom.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As a Abdul mentioned, this sort of question has come up a lot before ([another example](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1053/7) that looked at how to actually start with running DFT calcs). If after reading these (and checking out some of the resources they recommend) you still have some specific questions about getting started, feel free to ask another question or hop into a relevant chat room.